Trouble with image based printing on Epson impact printers with Epson Printer Android SDK (Kotlin)
I'm having some issues that I've described here in an issue on the Epson GH repo. Looking at the open issues, it doesn't look like Epson responds.
I'm wondering if anyone here has experience with this SDK to help answer some questions or point me in the right direction. Please see my issue in the GH link.
